# expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket' in Arm Template when parsing if statment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to set a variable in the variables section of an ARM template using the if function.
in the parameter section I've definded a parameter that is been filled by a parameter file. let's call it `condition`:

```
"condition": {
  "type": "bool",
  "defaultValue": false}
```

now in the variables section I would like to define a variable that if `condition` is `true` then `var = ["1","2","3"]` else `var = []` an empty array.

I've tried:

```
"var" : "[if(parameters('condition'),[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"],[])]"
"var" : "[if(parameters('condition'),['1','2','3'],[])]"
"var" : "[if(parameters('condition'),array(['1','2','3']),array([]))]"
```

all with the same result `expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'`
error thrown.

of course I can solve it in a similar way to:

```
"var0" : ["1","2","3"],
"var1" : [],
"var" : "[if(parameters('condition'),variables('var0'),variables('var1')]"
```

but that would lead to two dummy variables and an uglier code, and I would really like to avoid it.

trying to deploy from azure CLI.

It is surly a syntax error but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Turn's out the answer is just to use the built-in `json()` function.

I've solved it with:

```
"var" : "[if(parameters('condition'),json('[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]'),json('[]'))]"
```